# inline list middle section dropping?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Ok so I have created a fiddle to ensure it was no conflict with other styles on my page

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/5Bc8V/)

The problem is I have an inline list consisting of a header in each and some text underneath - the middle one seems to dropped down by a few pixels but not sure why or where that is coming from? I have tried altering margins - I have tried negative margins to bring it back up but nothing seems to work...?

```
<h2 style="text-align:center; margin: 0 auto; color: #CCC; font-size: 35px;">WHAT WE DO</h2>


<div style="width: 900px; margin: 0 auto;">


<ul style="width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;">

    <li style="width: 290px; display: inline-block;"><h3 style="color: #CCC;">OUR TEAM</h3>
            <p style="color: #000; font-size: 17px; line-height: 27px; font-weight: 300;">Our team builds mobile, tablet and web-based applications designed to streamline processes, increasing profitability and employee engagement. Our primary goal is to change the way our clients work for the better.</p></li>

    <li style="width: 290px; display: inline-block;"><h3 style="color: #CCC;">CLIENT EXPERIENCE</h3>
            <p style="color: #000; font-size: 17px; line-height: 27px; font-weight: 300;">We aim to provide the best experience possible. Our clients remain informed and involved at every step of a project, up to delivery and beyond. We take pride in our service.</p></li>

    <li style="width: 290px; display: inline-block; "><h3 style="color: #CCC;">BETTER BY DESIGN</h3>
            <p style="color: #000; font-size: 17px; line-height: 27px; font-weight: 300;">Design and creative thinking are key parts of the service we offer. We take great care in how our software looks and operates, challenging every aspect from the perspective of both the business and its users.</p></li>


</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top;` to inline css of the 2nd li which is dropping down. Or its best to give this style for all the list items like this

```
ul li{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```